# NoClassDefFoundError raised by Spark when master is setted to yarn-client

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jodatime, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I have a simple spark (1.4.1 version) application written in Scala that consume data from a kinesis stream. If i run the application, using the *spark-submit* command, with the value for the master setted to *local[*]* everything works fine. If i choose to use as master *yarn-client* i have the following exception:

```
15/11/24 14:22:09 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 1: Error starting receiver 1 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.<clinit>(AWS4Signer.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.createSigner(SignerFactory.java:119)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.lookupAndCreateSigner(SignerFactory.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.getSigner(SignerFactory.java:78)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByServiceRegion(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:307)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByURI(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:280)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:160)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.setEndpoint(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2102)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.init(AmazonKinesisClient.java:216)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.<init>(AmazonKinesisClient.java:202)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.<init>(AmazonKinesisClient.java:175)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:92)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisReceiver.onStart(KinesisReceiver.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more
```

Obviously i have created a fat jar using the assembly plugin for sbt that include the spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10 library that has joda-time-2.9.1.jar as dependency. I've listed the file contained in my fat jar and the class is present. To be sure of its presence i've also tryed to use DateTimeFormat from the main class and i hadn't any problem.

I hope that someone could help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share spark-submit command ?

Comment: spark-submit --master yarn-client --class Main app.jar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the classpath entries from the spark "Application Detail UI" => "Environment" tab and check if you see any joda-time entires there.

Comment: In the environment page i don't see a joda-time entry because the library is contained in my fat jar that obviously i see as classpath entry.